# When calling gawk -v pwd=%cd% from windows batch file I lose the slashes

Tags: windows, batch-file, awk, gawk

I want to call an awk/gawk script from a windows script (batch file).

I also want to pass in the current directory. So I have the following line:

```
gawk -v pwd=%cd% -f myscript.awk sometextfiletoprocess.txt
```

In the batch file if I do `echo %cd%` I get "c:\dev\work\PIC\"

But in the awk script I have the following at the start:

```
BEGIN {
    print "pwd: " pwd
}
```

And this gives the output "c:devworkPIC" - so you can see I am losing all the slashes. I guess the awk does not like "\"? How can I get my slash's back?

**edit** I tried using quote around the %cd%: `gawk -v pwd="%cd%" -f myscript.awk sometextfiletoprocess.txt`. This had no effect :(

Comment: Try: `gawk -v pwd="%cd:\=\\%" -f myscript.awk sometextfiletoprocess.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-v` interprets escape sequences (see http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24) so I'm guessing that's what's causing your problem.

If you want anything including escapes passed to awk literally then you should use ENVIRON:

```
pwd="\foo\bar" awk 'BEGIN{pwd=ENVIRON["pwd"]; ...}'
```

or pass it as an arg along with the file names:

```
awk 'BEGIN{pwd=ARGV[2]; ARGV[2]=""; ARGC--; ...}' file "\foo\bar"
```

For example:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    print "pwd1:", pwd1

    print "---"

    pwd2=ENVIRON["pwd2"]
    print "pwd2:", pwd2

    print "---"

    pwd3=ARGV[ARGC-1]; ARGV[ARGC-1]=""; ARGC--
    print "pwd3:", pwd3
}

$ pwd2='c:\dev\work\PIC\' awk -v pwd1='c:\dev\work\PIC\' -f tst.awk 'c:\dev\work\PIC\'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\d' treated as plain `d'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\w' treated as plain `w'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\P' treated as plain `P'
pwd1: c:devworkPIC\
---
pwd2: c:\dev\work\PIC\
---
pwd3: c:\dev\work\PIC\
```

Modify the above UNIX syntax to perform the right Windows incantation (or better yet install/use cygwin).

Comment: Cool, I got the ARGC example working, didn't get the ENIRON working, maybe I needed to use `set pwd=...` instead of `pwd=...` in the batch file. But I prefer ARGC method. It looks like the awk script processes both arguments as though they are files unless you do the ARGC-- - is that why you have ARGC--, to "skip" that last input?

Comment: Yes it is. The only thing awk won't treat as a file in the arg list is text that contains an `=` sign, e.g. `awk -f script.awk foo=bar file` because awk assumes you're using that to set the variable `foo` to the value `bar` (so if your file name contains `=` then you need to use the full path `... ./foo=bar file`).